# pass "new Integer (any number)" as a parameter to the remove method of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

When I create an ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList
arr.add(1);
arr.add(3);
arr.add(34);
arr.add(13);
```

And then I try to delete an element passing as parameter `new Integer(34)`.

```
arr.remove(new Integer(34));
```

How does that line work?
Am I creating a new integer object?
No element should be deleted since the element created within the method is stored in a different memory location than the ones created in the ArrayList. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `new Integer(34)`, YES definitely it creates a new Integer object. But Integer class has overridden `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}


public int hashCode() {
    return Integer.hashCode(value);
}
```

In your code when you call `Arr.remove(new Integer(34))` method, from ArrayList `remove(Object o)` is called.

```
public boolean remove(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
                if (elementData[index] == null) {
                    fastRemove(index);
                    return true;
                }
        } else {
            for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
                if (o.equals(elementData[index])) {
                    fastRemove(index);
                    return true;
                }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

From the above code, you can see when `o (Object)` is not null, it calls `equals` to check the equality and remove the object from list. Thus your object is remove, even though it has different memory location.

**One more point:**

Consider using `Integer.valueOf(34)` method rather than `new Integer(34)`. `Integer.valueOf(34)` will give you existing instance if already created in code at some other place. As Integer is immutable it won't create any issue. So no need to create new object every time using `new` keyword.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me with my question. thanks for including code, your answer was the best

Answer (score 2):

Internally, `java.util.ArrayList` using `.equals()` to do the comparison when try to remove an element from the list.

In your case, it will remove the element with value `34` because it is a wrapper type for `int` which is an `Object`.

But if you using the primitive type, it will throw `IndexOutOfBoundException`.
This is because it will call another `remove()` method which accept primitive type and this method will remove element at index 34 which it doesn't exist in above list with only has 4 elements.

By the way, you shouldn't use constructor method for any wrapper classes in future, because it already deprecated since Java 9 and it will be removed in Java 16. You should use static `.valueOf()` method when create wrapper object for primitive type.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me with my question.

Answer (score 0):

First, you could simply cast to `Integer`. Second, you should prefer Java naming conventions. Third, `Arrays.asList` is much less awkward. Fourth, you can print the `List`. Finally, (as you suspected) there is more at work here. Only values in the range of **`byte`** are guaranteed to be cached when using `new Integer(int)` (so you should probably avoid that, and either cast or use `Integer.valueOf(int)`).

```
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 34, 13));
System.out.println(al);
al.remove((Integer) 34);
System.out.println(al);
```

Comment: If using `Arrays.asList()` in above question, it will throw `UnsupportedOperationException` when calling `remove()` because the `List` class return by `Arrays.asList()` is immutable.

Comment: @MKTan That's why I used `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 34, 13))` - it works as expected.

Comment: Oops. Didn't saw that. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
According to Arraylist implementation remove method is based on equals().

    For Integer equals is overridden as follow and based on int value but not on object reference
```

Integer equals

```
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if(obj instanceof Integer){
        return value==((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```